# How to store UNIX timestamps with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, unix

**Some background:**

My website depends heavily on coordinating users across all kinds of different time zones.

I am using Carbon to handle my time zone conversions and calculations on the server side and moment.js on the client.

As a result the design choice was made that all date times (e.g. the start time of an event) would be stored as unix timestamps.

**Problem**

I am a bit confused by the definition of a "timestamp". In PHPMyAdmin the timestamp is not a unix timestamp but rather a date format:

```
2016-10-06 20:50:46
```

So if you want to have a default field of the current timestamp then you get the current date in GMT.

This makes things more complicated to convert back into a users timezone compared to a unix timestamp integer...

**Question:**

What field type should I store my unix timestamps as, currently I am using `int(11)` with a default of `none`. By extension... is there a way to store the current unix timestamp (e.g. 1475971200) by default in MySQL?

Comment: You can circumvent the problem by converting the datetime from and to unix timestamp. So to insert a unix timestamp, you would create a DATETIME field in your table, and convert the unix timestamp with `FROM_UNIXTIME(1514789942)`. Then when you want to retrieve the value back in unix timstamp you do `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(my_datetime_field)`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A Unix timestamp is a large integer (the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC), so `INT(11)` is the correct datatype.

Unfortunately, I don't think there's any way to specify a default that will insert the current timestamp. You'll need to call `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` explicitly when inserting, and use that. Function calls aren't allowed in `DEFAULT` specifications.

Comment: Why is it 11 bytes?

Comment: It isn't 11 bytes, it's 11 decimal digits, which is how many digits a 32-bit number can show.

Comment: INT(11) won't do the trick, just tried it, stores 2147483647 for 1623925731158. BIGINT does the trick.

Comment: @DBencz `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is measured in seconds, and the MySQL timestamp functions only support values up to `2**31-1`, which fits in `INT(11)`. You seem to have added 3 digits (milliseconds).

Answer (score 3):

You can continue using an unsigned INT, but you'll have to manually set the timestamp on insert (`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`).

Or you can use the TIMESTAMP type with the default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (which is stored as an int behind the scenes) and convert it to an int when selecting:
`SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(foo_field) FROM foo_table`

Reference - [Is it possible to create a column with a UNIX_TIMESTAMP default in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331026/is-it-possible-to-create-a-column-with-a-unix-timestamp-default-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you have to use either `bigint` or `varchar` because the maximum for `int(11)` is 2'147'483'647 (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255724/incorrect-integer-2147483647-is-inserted-into-mysql)).

Then, as the previous answers say, you have to manually insert `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`

Comment: Int(11) is enough, no need for bigint. unix timestamp can't go further than 19. january 2038 anyway because its usually a signed 32bit integer. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: Unix timestamp is seconds not miliseconds. You wont need bigger than int(11).
People get confused because javascript Date.now()  returns miliseconds instead. you need to divide it by 1000