# How to set default value of a mysql column as unix_timestamp?

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I was thinking at something like this:

```
`post_modified` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT UNIX_TIMESTAMP (NOW ()) ON UPDATE UNIX_TIMESTAMP (NOW ()),
```

But this code it is not working.

Comment: Not possible. Default values cannot be dynamic, EXCEPT in the case of `timestamp` fields. You'll have to use a trigger to set a unix timestamp.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331026/is-it-possible-to-create-a-column-with-a-unix-timestamp-default-in-mysql -- Check this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Note : I have no idea about the performance of **MYSQL  TRIGGER**
>
> Please go through these links
>
> 1. [Identify some of the drawback of implementing sql server triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170837/identify-some-of-the-drawback-of-implementing-sql-server-triggers)
> 2. [Using Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)

You can create triggers for this.

> **for insertion**

`CREATE TRIGGER {trigger_name} BEFORE INSERT ON {table_name} FOR EACH ROW SET new.{field_name} = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());`

> **for update**

`CREATE TRIGGER {trigger_name} BEFORE UPDATE ON {table_name} FOR EACH ROW SET new.{field_name} = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());`

Answer (score 6):

Nope you cant use it as you showed.

From Data Type doc on [MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-defaults.html):

"The default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP column."

Look at below answer for workaround:

[Is it possible to create a column with a UNIX_TIMESTAMP default in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331026/is-it-possible-to-create-a-column-with-a-unix-timestamp-default-in-mysql)

Hope this will help !